# where can I find the original Ethereum's (DAO's) genesis file?

Tags: go-ethereum

Where can I find the source code (genesis.json) of the genesis block for Ethereum's main net (i.e the DAO's) ???

Looking for any .json file within the source code didn't produce any results. This file must produce the hash = 0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3, which is the hash of the genesis block.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I also had to search quite a while to find the genesis block, so it may still help others searching for it. It can be found in the ethereumj project on Github:

https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/blob/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/resources/genesis/frontier.json

Comment: thanks. I got it from the State of block 0, there is a dump function to dump all state accounts. And it is also stored in `core/genesis_alloc.go` and there is also a decoding function to extract it