# Original genesis.json file for ethereum mainnet, which should have 314 accounts allocation?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, genesis

314 accounts are created at the start of ethereum frontier release and some funds were alloted to them. 
https://www.etherchain.org/charts/totalAccounts

where can I get the genesis.json file used to create those 314 accounts on ethereum on 30 july 2015.

Thanks,
Shrey Baheti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where can I find the original Ethereum's (DAO's) genesis file?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32366/where-can-i-find-the-original-ethereums-daos-genesis-file)

Comment: I need the initial file not after the DAO's attack. These file has around 9000 accounts created.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 314 accounts are created at the start of ethereum frontier release and some funds were alloted to them. https://www.etherchain.org/charts/totalAccounts

I'm not sure this is correct. There are 8947 Ethereum presale transactions from 8890 distinct addresses. There are 2 anomalous empty addresses, thought to be a result of a buggy genesis tool, and then there are the Foundation addresses.

So around 9000 accounts at genesis.

I'd suspect the chart you've referenced doesn't include the genesis accounts, but only considers user-created accounts after the start of the chain.

Sources:

- [Overview: Ethereum’s initial public sale](https://keepingstock.net/overview-ethereum-s-initial-public-sale-563c05e95501)
- [Ethereum Blog: Final Steps](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/07/27/final-steps/) - You can run the tool described to generate the genesis file yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is world first Ethereum account 0xD1648503B1CCC5B8BE03FA1EC4F3EE267E6ADF7B in genesis 5,828ETH I found it in go-ethereum source code